# Prove that the set $\{x_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup\{a\}$ is sequentially compact using sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

**NOTE:** This question has been asked more than once, but the other answers use open covers, not sequences, and do not interest me at the moment. I just want more refined mathematicians to look at my proof attempt, correct, improve, or criticize.

**STATEMENT:** 
Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and let $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $X$ that converges to $a\in X$.
Prove that the set $\{x_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup\{a\}$ is compact.

**ATTEMPT:** 
Let $a=x_\infty$ and $S=\{x_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup\{x_\infty\}$.

**Case 1:** $x_n$ has finitely many values.
$$S \text{ is finite}\Longrightarrow S \text{ is compact}$$

**Case 2:** $x_n$ has infinitely many values.

Let $(y_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}} \in S$ be an arbitrary sequence. 
(Not necessarily a subsequence of $x_n$, can be a reordering)

Let $f:=y_k\to n$ and $g:=n \to k$. 
($f$ maps the value of $(y_k)$ to the index of the corresponding $x_n$) 
($g$ maps that index back to the index of $y_k$)

Let $y_{k_l}$ be a subsequence of $y_k$ such that:
$$\cases{k_0=g(0)\\
k_l=g\bigg(\text{min}\big\{ f\big((y_k)_{k>k_{l-1}}\big)\big\}\bigg)}$$

(I am sorry about this horrible behemoth. What I want it to do is:)

1. Start at the index of $y_k=x_0$.

   Map all the succeeding terms of $y_k$ to their $n$-value.

   Take the minimum $n$.

   Map that minimum to its $k$-value.

Example: 
 
$(y_k)=(x_9,x_2,x_0,x_5,x_1,x_7,x_3,...)$ 
$(y_{k_l})=(x_0,x_1,x_3,...)$

The resulting subsequence $(y_{k_l})$ of $(y_k)$ is also a subsequence of $(x_n)$.

Since $x_n \to x_\infty$ then $y_{k_l} \to x_\infty$.

Therefore $\forall y_k \in S, \exists y_{k_l} \to x_\infty \in S$.

Therefore $S$ is compact.

I am well-aware how inelegant this proof is. 
I am not even sure if it is correctly written or expressed. 
Help, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your idea will work, but I agree that the notation and write-up could use some improvement. Since you have an algorithm in mind, let’s use a proof with an algorithm. Let’s consider the set
$$N_0=\{n\in \mathbb{N}:x_n\in (y_k)\}.$$
Then $N_0$ is non-empty and a subset of the natural numbers, so it has a minimum, say $n_0$. Let us set $z_0=x_{n_0}$. Now construct
$$N_1=\{n\in \mathbb{N}:x_n\in (y_k), n>n_0\}=N_0\cap \{n\in\mathbb{N}:n>n_0\}.$$
If $N_1$ is empty, then $(y_k)$ was constant, so it converges. Thus, we may assume $N_1\neq\emptyset$. Take the minimum, $n_1$. Set $z_1=x_{n_1}$.   Inductively construct this sequence and then you can “observe” (as you did above) that it is a subsequence of $(y_k)$ and a subsequence of $(x_k)$, so it will converge.

---

For good measure, I will write out one more step:
Let $$N_2=N_{1}\cap \{n\in \mathbb{N}:n>n_{1}\}.$$
If $N_2$ is empty, then $(y_k)$ contains only $2$ distinct values, and we may find a subsequence of it that converges (the idea is that at least one of the values must be repeated infinitely often, and there are only finitely-many values, so we just pick the constant subsequence whose value is the one that is repeated infinitely-often). Otherwise, we have a minimum for $N_2$ say $n_2$ and set $z_2=x_{n_2}$.
At each stage, this algorithm either terminates with us choosing a constant subsequence, or it does not and we construct a sequence
$(z_i)=(x_{n_i})$ which converges because $(x_n)$ does.

Comment: The two criticisms I have are this: you may not be able to choose $x_0$ to be the starting point because $(y_k)$ may not contain $x_0$. This is handled when I construct $N_0$. You don’t really need to define these functions or $x_{\infty}$, but you can if you want to. Otherwise, your idea seems like it should work. Let me know what you think of my proof.

Comment: Extremely perceptive remarks and a **way** cleaner reformulation of the ideas. I applaud your clever approach!
I admit the algorithmic approach was kind of a programmatic dirty hack rather than an elegant proof.

I want to mull over your proof a bit and try to extend it to an infinite intersection of $N_i$; with case 1 covering all finite sets, and case 2 covering that specific infinite set. Once I reach a good end I promise to tick your answer.

Loving your proof, and thanks for the cleanup!

Comment: I based my algorithm on your example, so it appears to me that you had a clear idea of why the sequence $(y_k)$ should have a convergent subsequence. Glad it helped.